# How to keep/assign node names when contracting vertices in igraph?

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to contract some vertices in igraph (using the python api) while keeping the names of the vertices. It isn't clear to me how to keep the name attribute of the graph. The nodes of the graph are people and I'm trying to collapse people with corrupted names.

I looked at the R documentation and I still don't see how to do it.

For example, if I do either of the following I get an error.

```
smallgraph.contract_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,2,6],vertex.attr.comb=[name='first'])

smallgraph.contract_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,2,6],vertex.attr.comb=['first'])
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the keyword argument you need is called `combine_attrs` and not `vertex.attr.comb`. See `help(Graph.contract_vertices)` from the Python command line after having imported igraph. Also, the keyword argument accepts either a single specifier (such as `first`) or a dictionary. Your first example is invalid because it is simply not valid Python syntax. The second example won't work because you pass a *list* with a single item instead of just the single item.

So, the correct variants would be:

```
smallgraph.contract_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,2,6], combine_attrs=dict(name="first"))
smallgraph.contract_vertices([0,1,2,3,4,2,6], combine_attrs="first")
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. You can just enter a dictionary without using the wording

```
vertex.attr.comb
```